# Cokernel of a morphism of invertible sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface over the field of complex numbers. Suppose I have an injective morphism of invertible sheaves on $X$, say,

$$0\rightarrow M\rightarrow N.$$

Consider the cokernel $T$, a torsion sheaf. Assume the support of $T$ is a smooth curve $C$ on $X$. What can we say about $T|_C$? Will it be torsion-free and hence locally free? Or can it have some torsion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you restrict the exact sequence
$$
0 \to M \to N \to T \to 0
$$
to $C$, you will get a right exact sequence
$$
M\vert_C \to N\vert_C \to T\vert_C \to 0.
$$
By definition of $C$ the first map vanishes, hence $T\vert_C \cong N\vert_C$ is a line bundle on $C$.

Comment: why does the first map vanish? Can you please explain more?

Comment: does $C$ being the support mean the map becomes zero?